# Changing UWP project's Target Version from 1803 to 1809 disables NavigationView's Acrylic texture - why?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have an UWP project which I started to build using Target Version 1803. When I upgraded the solution to use Target Version 1809 my NavigationView's behaviour changed and the acrylic effect was gone.

As an illustration, this is what it looked like before:

[image]

And this is what it looks like now:

[image]

Why does this happen? I wouldn't believe this is to match some design guidelines since Microsoft themselves still use the acrylic effect in NavigationViews in many native UWP programs. I would also like to know if there's a way to "bring back" the acrylic to a NavigationView in a program using Target Version 1809.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In latest version 17763, The value of `NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground` change to `SolidColorBrush`. The following is the different between version 17134 and 17763.

**17134**

```
<StaticResource x:Key="NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground" ResourceKey="SystemControlChromeMediumLowAcrylicWindowMediumBrush" />
```

**17763**

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground" Color="{StaticResource SystemChromeMediumColor}" />
```

If you want to implement acrylic effect, you could add the first `StaticResource` in your page resource like the following

```
<Page.Resources>
    <StaticResource  x:Key="NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground"
                     ResourceKey="SystemControlChromeMediumLowAcrylicWindowMediumBrush"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

Comment: Where should I look to to keep track of these changes?

Comment: The style stored in the `generic.xaml` file.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT the `StaticResource` code above doesn't seem to work with Dark and Light theming. It always stays with the Dark `AcrylicBrush` I've defined when I toggle between app's Light or Dark.

Comment: hi @CarloMendoza, Could you create a new thread with reproduce steps and let me know, if it is bug, I will report it.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT: done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54977512/fluent-acrylicbrush-does-not-switch-between-light-dark-theme-etc-uwp

Comment: Yep, I got it. I will check.