# Fluent AcrylicBrush does not switch between Light, Dark, theme etc. UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-template-studio

Defined Light theme (`<AcrylicBrush` `TintColor="Red"/>`), Dark, (`<AcrylicBrush` `TintColor="Orange"/>`) in App.xaml. Per this post, [Changing UWP project's Target Version from 1803 to 1809 disables NavigationView's Acrylic texture - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53937941/changing-uwp-projects-target-version-from-1803-to-1809-disables-navigationview), I added the following to ShellPage.xaml. The expected behavior when I toggle between Light and Dark theme is that the app `NavigationView` control will have an `AcrylicBrush` tint that toggles between Red and Orange. In the definition below, actual behavior is it stays Orange.

ShellPage.xaml:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <StaticResource  x:Key="NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground"
                     ResourceKey="MyAcrylicBrush"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

App.xaml:

```
<Application
x:Class="TEST.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
                <AcrylicBrush x:Key="MyAcrylicBrush"
                              BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop"
                              TintColor="Green"
                              TintOpacity="0.8" />
                <AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewDefaultPaneBackground"
                              BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop"
                              TintColor="Green"
                              TintOpacity="0.8" />
                <AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewTopPaneBackground"
                              BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop"
                              TintColor="Green"
                              TintOpacity="0.8" />
                <AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground"
                              BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop"
                              TintColor="Green"
                              TintOpacity="0.8" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                <AcrylicBrush x:Key="MyAcrylicBrush"
                              BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop"
                              TintColor="Orange"
                              TintOpacity="0.8" />
                <AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewDefaultPaneBackground"
                              BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop"
                              TintColor="Orange"
                              TintOpacity="0.8" />
                <AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewTopPaneBackground"
                              BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop"
                              TintColor="Orange"
                              TintOpacity="0.8" />
                <AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground"
                              BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop"
                              TintColor="Orange"
                              TintOpacity="0.8" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                <AcrylicBrush x:Key="MyAcrylicBrush"
                              BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop"
                              TintColor="Red"
                              TintOpacity="1"/>
                <AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewDefaultPaneBackground"
                              BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop"
                              TintColor="Red"
                              TintOpacity="1" />
                <AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewTopPaneBackground"
                              BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop"
                              TintColor="Red"
                              TintOpacity="1" />
                <AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground"
                              BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop"
                              TintColor="Red"
                              TintOpacity="1"/> 
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can directly give the Key(NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackGround) to your AcrylicBrush. So it will change your navigation view background.

```
  <Page.Resources>
      <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                    <AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground" BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop" TintColor="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColorDark1}" FallbackColor="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColorDark1}" TintOpacity="0.80"/>   
                </ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                    <AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground" BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop" TintColor="{ThemeResource SystemAltHighColor}" FallbackColor="#333333" TintOpacity="0.50"/>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```

[image]
Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Changing exactly that gives me this exception. `Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException: 'XAML parsing failed.'`

Comment: I will edit my answer as you are looking to apply acrylic brush to NavigationViewPane

Comment: This seems to allow me to work around the issue. However, it doesn't seem to be how the Microsoft team intend this to be. Thank you @Vignesh

Answer (score 0):

If you use `StaticResource`, it will keep the brush it from the first evaluation. However, you should not have to provide the resource on `ShellPage` at all and what you have in `App.xaml` should be enough - you have a brush called `NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground` there and this brush should automatically override the `NavigationPane` default (the linked question talked specifically about the case when the resource's name is different from the built-in one). Moreover, it should work according to the current theme as it is part of theme dictionaries.

Try deleting the `<StaticResource>` element from `ShellPage` to see if it solves the problem.

I tested this change and it works properly.

**Light theme**

[image: Light theme]

**Dark theme**

[image: Dark theme]

Comment: Unfortunately, the AcrylicBrush effect is lost with this. In full screen mode of the app, the `NavigationView` does not have transparency.

Comment: You may not use `TintOpacity` set to 1. This makes the tint fully opaque. Try using something like 0.5 and you will definitely see through.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I had TintOpacity all the way down to "0.1" and even "0.01" first--that's how I discovered something's off. I turned it up to "1" so switching between Light/Dark was obvious. Curious, where are you binding `MyAcrylicBrush` in your XAML?

Comment: I was not using MyAcrylicBrush at all. I just left the contents of App.xaml the same as you had, but never utilized MyAcrylicBrush, only the brush with default name as I mentioned in the answer :-)

Comment: Got it. Are you on 17763 or 17134? What you have basically puts me back to square one--the genesis of the question. I agree that it should work, but it somehow doesn't include the `NavigationView` control. I see all other controls toggle Light/Dark.

Comment: Have you removed the <Page.Resources> section from ShellPage? I am on 1809 too

Comment: Could you please post your sample project to GitHub so that I can have a look?

Comment: Hi! tried your app now, and I probably know what is happening. If I move the whole <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries> content to the `ShellPage` <Page.Resources> section, it starts working as expected. The reason is probably that the ThemeDictionaries are evaluated *before* the `<XamlControlsResources>` entry in `Application.xaml`, which overrides them with the built-in theme resource